# Redirect Devise before_filter :authenticate_user to sign in path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise and have a quick question. How can I redirect the :authenticate_user! before_filter to the user sign up page instead of sign in?  I've been going through https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb but haven't had much luck figuring out a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're going to have to create a custom FailureApp that inherits from Devise's FailureApp as seen here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

Comment: The issue with this approach (for the one in this link at least) is that it pushes you to signup if you fail to put in your password correctly on signup (for example)...

Comment: this is best practice answer, don't result to implement own `before_filter`  solution !

Answer (score 45):

I had a similar issue where I needed to redirect to the signup if the user was not logged in.
I fixed it by adding a method to the application_controller.rb and using it as a before filter in the other controllers.

Keep in mind that is is more of a temporary solution because it skips a bunch of devise´s abstractions.

```
before_filter :auth_user

  def auth_user
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url unless user_signed_in?
  end
```

Comment: Not exactly the same functionality as `authenticate_user!`, which redirects back to the previous page after signup.

Comment: Yeah true, Not exactly the same but it is temporary solution. Can go for this.Thank you so much.

Comment: it works but it's skips several layers of Devise abstractions. `Steve` answer above is more best practice, while this is more of "quick temp fix while we figure it out properly". If you introduce more requirements in your app then you are "dooomed" :)

Comment: This is a bad approach for the reasons mentioned (it bypasses much of Devise's "behind the scenes" functionality). See my answer, based on Steve's answer, for a working example of the correct way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I added a wiki page showing the correct way to do this with a failure app (as Steven initially hinted at):

- [Redirect to new registration (sign up) path if unauthenticated](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Redirect-to-new-registration-(sign-up)-path-if-unauthenticated)

The key is to override the `route` method, like so:

```
# app/lib/my_failure_app.rb
class MyFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def route(scope)
    :new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

and then have Devise use your failure app:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = MyFailureApp
end
```

This approach is preferable to overriding `authenticate_user!` in your controller because it won't clobber a lot of "behind the scenes" stuff Devise does, such as storing the attempted URL so the user can be redirected after successful sign in.

## With multiple user types

If you have `Admin` and `User` Devise resources, you'll probably want to keep the default "new session" functionality for admins. You can do so quite easily by checking what type of scope is being processed:

```
# app/lib/my_failure_app.rb
class MyFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def route(scope)
    scope.to_sym == :user ? :new_user_registration_url : super
  end
end
```